# static file downloading not working in angular 4

Tags: angular

I trying into download static file from HTML .It's not working

app.routing.ts

```
   { path: 'application', component: ApplicationComponent},
    // otherwise redirect to home
   { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home' }
```

html

```
  <a href="/excel_files/xxx.xlsx" target="_self" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Spread Sheet</a>
```

Here is link - http://localhost:4200/excel_files/xxx.xlsx

But it's redirect into home.

Thanks.

Comment: did you use angualr.cli

Comment: yes sir. i am using angular cli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the answer

Please add the download attribute to the  tag. This will prevent rout changes and tell the browser it is a download link:

```
<a href="/excel_files/file_name.xlsx" target="_self" download>
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Spread Sheet
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Robert  File download sucessfully. But showing xxx.xlsx Failed - No file in chrome

Comment: angular_project/src/excel_files/file_name.xlsx

Comment: check the answer change path according to your folder tree